# Vacuous truth: can something exist and not exist at the same time?

Tags: truth

Any square isn't round, so I use "round square".

1. A round sqaure exists
2. A round sqaure doesn't exist.

Are they both (vacuously) true because any square isn't round?

Comment: No. And they are not both true, "round square exists" is false. The effect of attaching two contradictory predicates to an object is exactly that such an object does not exist. You are probably confusing "round square exists" with an implication that has a false premise (and hence is vacuously true), but it is not of that form.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we describe round square, which doesn't exist?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/105176/can-we-describe-round-square-which-doesnt-exist)

Comment: "A round square exists" means "There is an object x such that (x is Square and x is Round)" and is simply FALSE, because there is no object that has both properties.

Answer (score 1):

The word 'exist' can be used in different ways, so an entity can exist in one sense of the word and not exist in another. For example, Sherlock Holmes exists as a fictional character, but does not exist as a real person. A square circle can exist as a concept or expression, but cannot exist as a geometrical figure that you might draw on paper.

Comment: If a square circle doesn't exist anywhere, even as a concept, can I  still say "a square circle doesn't exist"? Because to say of something, it must exist somewhere, even as a concept?

Comment: Clearly a square circle exists as a concept because you and many other people have raised questions about it.

Comment: Then, nothing doesn't exist? Because a tall short ruler, bright dark light or colorless green ideas all exist at least as a concept?

Comment: @Collins yes. Everything exists. Now, we need to define a new word that means: *actually, really, truly, definitely exists*. Or, we could stick with the original word.

Answer (score 1):

A "round square" - unless you make a definition of it - is considered in common sense as a contradiction.

A "round square" exists (for example) in the world of contradictions, is true.

A "round square" exists, as a shape is not true; it cannot be drawn on paper.

But "a round square exists" and "a round square doesn't exists" cannot be both true - in any context - according to the *principle of non-contradiction*.

Comment: I mean, even if a round square exists at least in the world of contradictions, does everything people talk about exists at least as a concept?

Answer (score 0):

(See my other comment on your questions) propositions are sometimes called "truth barers" that are true or false depending on the way the world is/a state of affairs. So a proposition about a round square is always false because it is impossible for a round square to exist in the ordinary sense of existing.